# UDP Talker gives "Bad value for ai_flags" on sendto() call

Tags: sockets, udp, sendto

I am stuck with my UDP talker app.
The goal for the moment is to initialize the server, register a client and then proceed to send something to that client.
I've worked my way through Beej's network guide and coded the following library implementation:

This inizializes the server

```
int init_udp_server(const char *port_string){

  /** Check the input data **/
  if(port_string == NULL)
    port_string = DEFAULT_PORT;

  /** Get the information for the server **/
  memset(&addrinfo_hints, 0, sizeof addrinfo_hints);
  /* Use either protocol (v4, v6) */
  addrinfo_hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  /* Use UDP socket type */
  addrinfo_hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
  /* Use system IP */
  addrinfo_hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

  if( (ret = getaddrinfo(NULL, port_string, &addrinfo_hints, &addrinfo_server)) 
      != 0 ){
    printf("Server:getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(ret));  
    return -1;
  }

  /** Loop through the list returned by getaddrinfo and get socket **/
  for( addrinfo_queue = addrinfo_server; addrinfo_queue != NULL; 
      addrinfo_queue = addrinfo_queue->ai_next){
    if((sockfd = socket(addrinfo_queue->ai_family,
            addrinfo_queue->ai_socktype, addrinfo_queue->ai_protocol)) == -1){
      error("Server: get socket failed");
      continue;
    }
    if(bind(sockfd, addrinfo_queue->ai_addr, addrinfo_queue->ai_addrlen)
        == -1){
      close(sockfd);
      error("Server: Bind to socket error");
      continue;
    }
    break;

  }
  /* If we got to addrinfo_queue == NULL, we did not get a valid socket */
  if(addrinfo_queue == NULL){
    error("Server: Could not bind a socket");
    return -1;
  }
  /* We do not need the addrinfo_server anymore */
  freeaddrinfo(addrinfo_server);
  return 0;
}
```

This registers the client

```
int udp_server_setup_client(const char *client_addr, const char *port_string, int     client_nr){


  /** Check the input data **/
  if(port_string == NULL)
    port_string = DEFAULT_PORT;
  if(client_addr == NULL){
    error("No valid client list");
    return -1;
  }
  if(client_nr < 0 || client_nr > 7){
    error("No valid client Nr.");
    return -1;
  } 

  memset(&addrinfo_hints, 0, sizeof addrinfo_hints);
  /* Use either protocol (v4, v6) */
  addrinfo_hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  /* Use UDP socket type */
  addrinfo_hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

  /* Get the information for the client */
  if( (ret = getaddrinfo( client_addr, port_string, &addrinfo_hints,
          &current)) != 0 ){
    printf("Client:getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(ret));  
    return -1;
  }
  else{
    /* We read out the IP, kind of a nice check to see wheter all went fine */
    char ip4[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    struct sockaddr_in *sa = (struct sockaddr_in*) current->ai_addr;
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sa->sin_addr),ip4, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("Clients address: %s\n",ip4);
    addrinfo_clients[client_nr] = current;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And finally this is for writing

```
int udp_server_write(const char *buffer, int buffer_size, int client_nr){
  /* Sanity check of the input */
  if(client_nr > (MAX_NR_CLIENTS - 1) || client_nr < 0){
    error("Not a valid client");
    return -1;
  }
  if(buffer == NULL){
    error("Not a valid buffer address");
    return -1;
  }
  /* Just so we type less */
  current = addrinfo_clients[client_nr];

  socklen = sizeof current->ai_addr; 
  if((ret = sendto(sockfd, (void*)buffer, buffer_size, 0,
        (sockaddr*)current->ai_addr, socklen)) == -1){
    printf("Failed to send message to client %i\n", client_nr);
    printf("Error Code: %s\n",gai_strerror(ret)); 
    return -1;    
    }
  else if(ret < buffer_size){
    printf("Wrote only %i of %i bytes\n", ret, buffer_size);
    return -1;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

I call the functions like this

```
init_udp_server("3334"); 

udp_server_setup_client("192.168.1.5", "3334", 0);

udp_server_write(send_buf, 256, 0);
```

As soon as sendto() is called I get an error:
    Failed to send message to client 0
    Error Code: Bad value for ai_flags
I checked it with gdb and found that the addrinfo struct is filled correctly, and the address of the client is valid.
Any one an idea where to look? I am running out of ideas...

thanks, wenzlern

Comment: From the manpage of getaddrinfo:  EAI_BADFLAGS
hints.ai_flags contains invalid flags; or, hints.ai_flags included AI_CANONNAME and name was NULL.  I don't know how one of these could apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `sendto()`, the last parameter is being set to `sizeof current->ai_addr`, which is wrong. `current->ai_addr` is defined as a `sockaddr*` pointer, so `sizeof current->ai_addr` will always return 4 on a 32-bit system and 8 on a 64-bit system. It just happens that IPv4 addresses are 4 bytes in size, so `sizeof current->ai_addr` will only work for IPv4 addresses on 32-bit systems, but will always fail for IPv6 addresses on 32-bit systems and all addresses on 64-bit systems.  You need to use `current->ai_addrlen` instead of `sizeof`.

Also, passing -1 to `gai_strerror()` is not valid.  It expects you to pass in a real error code, such as the return value of `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()`.  `sendto()` does not return an actual error code.  When it fails, you have to use `WSAGetLastError()` on Windows or `errno` on other systems to get the actual error code.

Try this:

```
if ((ret = sendto(sockfd, (char*)buffer, buffer_size, 0, (sockaddr*)current->ai_addr, current->ai_addrlen)) == -1)
{
    #ifdef _WIN32
    ret = WSAGetLastError();
    #else
    ret = errno;
    #endif

    printf("Failed to send message to client %i\n", client_nr);
    printf("Error Code: (%d) %s\n", ret, gai_strerror(ret)); 
    return -1;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your corrections solved the problem. I am working on a 64bit machine, so it did fail constantly because of the socklen construct. Thanks again! Regards, wenzlern